# Cant use @click="somefunction()" on a vs-dropdown

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, web-frontend

As the title says, I'm unable to use the @click function in a vs-dropdown

```
<vs-dropdown>
  <a href="#" @click="funct('/parameter')">Home</a>
  <vs-dropdown-menu>
    <vs-dropdown-item>
    asdf
    </vs-dropdown-item>
  </vs-dropdown-menu>
</vs-dropdown>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({}),
  methods: {
    funct(param) {
      this.$routes.push(param)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I should be redirected to '/parameter' but instead whenever I click it nothing happens, is there a way to work around this or force the dropdown to do what I want?

Comment: Talked to the vuesax devs about this and they implemented the function @click the the vs-dropdown element in the 3.11.6 update, so it works now.

Answer (score 3):

It should be this.**$router**.push(param) **NOT** this.**$routes**.push(param)

Comment: yes! this was also a problem, aside from the fact that vs-dropdown didn't allow you to add the @click by the time I redacted this question.